# CSS HTML last child not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Hello i want all the thirth div in class : highLightBoxSmall to have margin-right: 0;

this is my html:

```
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment1.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment1.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment1.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
        <a href="assortimentoverzicht.html"><div class="highLightBoxSmall"> <img src="images/style/HighLightAssortiment2.png" class="highLightsImg mid" /> <span class="highLightHeader">Monitoren</span></div></a>
```

and this is my css:

```
.highLightBoxSmall:nth-child(3n+3) { 
margin-right: 0; 
}
```

when i remove the  it does work but with a it doesn't work.

when i try this:

```
.highLightBoxSmall a:nth-child(3n+3) { 
margin-right: 0; 
}
```

or this

```
.highLightBoxSmall a:link:nth-child(3n+3) { 
margin-right: 0;
```

}

all doesn't work.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you are using an *invalid markup* <sup>*(If not using HTML5)*</sup>, you cannot wrap the `div` tag using an `a` tag..

So consider altering the markup, and use the selector below..

```
div.highLightBoxSmall:nth-of-type(3n) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3UGK/)

If you want to target `a`, than just add `a` at the end of the selector

```
div.highLightBoxSmall:nth-of-type(3n) a {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

---

#### If you want to stick with your markup

*(I would consider altering instead)*

```
a:nth-of-type(3n) div.highLightBoxSmall {
    background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3UGK/1/)

Note: Make sure you wrap the `a` tags in a container element having an `id` or a `class` to uniquely target the `a` element. So assuming that if you are going with the above solution, so wrap the contents inside a `div` say with a `class` of `select_threes`, so use the selector below..

```
.select_threes a:nth-of-type(3n) div.highLightBoxSmall {
    background: #f00;
}
```

**You can get rid of `div.highLightBoxSmall` if you are targeting the `a` tag only.**

---

Also, would like to tell you that all your selectors are incorrect, in each selector, you are selecting `a` tag, nested under an element having `.highLightBoxSmall` `class` but none does.

It's better to use `nth-of-type()` here rather than using `nth-child()`

Comment: HTML5 does allow <a> elements to contain blockelements like <div>'s

Comment: @KristofFeys Also provided a demo without altering the markup

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

- There is no anchor inside `.highLightBoxSmall`, therefor the selector is wrong.
- You are requesting an nth child inside an element that has no multiple of the same elements.

You need a container that goes around the set of anchors:

```
<div id="containerId">
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
    <a class="anchorClass"></a>
</div>
```

Then you can create a selector as follows:

```
#containerId a.anchorClass:nth-of-type(3n){
    margin-right: 0; 
}
```